# Locked out of admin panel and can't get support

Tags: email

I cannot login to admin panel and every time I try to reset the password, I receive a password reset email that is broken/incomplete. The text stops mid sentence and where a link should follow, there is no link. I can't lodge a support ticket because Im using community edition. How can I get support? Please help.

Comment: Have you tried looking at your email source for the complete link? Probably the email client is breaking down the link.

Comment: Do you have access to the Database? If so I would update the password via the DB.